# Set HTML using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to change HTML using JQuery

```
jQuery("#message").html() = "Done";
```

but the console complains "Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" How can I make it valid?

Comment: You can find this on 1 minute of google. pls do some research before come here.

Comment: **Step 1:** Learn how to use the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2).

Comment: @Guerra Is there any problem if he come here directly? I mean is there any rules like that?

Comment: @Arif simple rule is to first read html() method documentation if you try to use .html() method

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 - We can still let people know they should read the documentation without being rude about it or condescending.  People are more likely to learn if they're not insulted. Remember, we were all new once. Again, that doesn't excuse the lack of effort, and this should be downvoted, but there's no need to be nasty. :)

Comment: Easier questions do allow less experienced members to try and help and raise their reputation too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close, you want

```
jQuery("#message").html("Done");
```

Answer (score 3):

It is

```
$('#message').html('Done');
```

Comment: Why are we downvoting correct answers posted within seconds of each other?  If it's because they leave out explanations, then I encourage answerers to expand their answer to make it better than the exact copies that are posted here.

Comment: I didn't downvote anything.

Comment: I know, this isn't targeted at you, just in general. :)

Comment: Thanks for the formatting, @jmort253. And btw: since the answers are identical, there isn't any reason to downvote.

Comment: maybe someone downvote to put his answer at the top, maybe, maybe not

Comment: @roasted - All of them were downvoted, so I suspect it's for a different reason. I may have spoken out of turn. :)

Comment: Sorry for posting the same answer. I didn't see yours until mine was submitted.

Answer (score 3):

```
jQuery("#message").html("Done");
```

Please read documentation you will feel better, at least your code...

Answer (score 2):

Or just

$`("#message").html("Done");`